# Replace spaces between first character and second one also reverse remove spaces between last and last but one?

Tags: php, regex, string

How to replace or remove spaces between first and second letter of a string and also remove space between last and last but one character using php ?

Example :

```
$string = "$ 1000,00 1000 10000 1000 $";
```

I want to display the string like

```
$string ="$1000,00 1000 10000 1000$";
```

Please help me ?

Comment: This question lacks research. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried with the same hints. Tell me if any url did you find.Please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace ('/^(.) (.*) (.)$/', '$1$2$3', $string);
```

Comment: I weak in preg regex.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace space by no space.

```
$string = str_replace(" ","",$string);
```

Comment: No, this is not correct

Comment: @soavahaf because you edited your question.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar that's right. He is trying to fool us by adding something in the question and then saying us that our answer is wrong

Comment: @soavahaf basically you posted a question, we answered and then you changed the question and then came to us that our answers are wrong. Do you think this is right behavior. We are not your freelancers who will write the full code for you. We can help you if you tried something.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$string = str_replace(" ", "", $string); // $1000$
```

Comment: This replaces all spaces, not just the first and last one.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah I knows this, but OP has edited his question..

Comment: No, this is not correct